# How to sell extensions using Akeeba Release Systems and Akeeba Subscriptions

Tags: joomla-3.x, extensions

I developed local payment gateway plugins for some Joomla components, and would love to sell them on my site, using Akeeba Release Systems and Akeeba Subscriptions.

Can someone please help put me through? The examples I see are for memberships, not software downloads, and frankly I need help.

I intend to sell each plugin separately, and provide support for each one using Akeeba Tickets System - the subscriber should only have access to the private support channel for the plugin(s) he has subscribed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, Akeeba Release System will manage the downloading and releasing of your plugins.

You will need to create a user group and a view access level for each plugin file (an item of Akeeba Rlease System), where downloading this plugin file is allowed only for users with the corresponding user group and view access.

On the other side, Akeeba subscriptions will manage the payments and subscriptions, you will create a subscription level for each plugin, each subscription level has 2 actions:

1. **Add to Joomla! user groups**: Users will be added to these Joomla! user groups when their subscription to this level is enabled.
2. **Remove from Joomla! user groups**: Users will be removed from these Joomla! user groups when their subscription to this level is disabled.

   The level is enabled when a user finalizes the payment for it, and disabled when it is expired or cancelled for any reason.

So, Akeeba Subscriptions will handle adding/removing users to Joomla user groups, and Joomla user groups are having view access, also Akeeba release items/files are controlled by view access, so only users having a valid subscription will be able to access and download the plugin they paid for.

I didn't play with Akeeba Tickets System, but I think it will integrate with Akeeba Subscriptions through the view access.